# How do I make a function that saves progress in Python?

Tags: python, save

I am currently making a text adventure in Python and I would like to know how to create a function that saves progress and another function that loads the last savepoint. How do I do this?

Comment: Usually you make a class that stores the state. You can then use for instance `pickle` to make it persistent.

Comment: Alright, how do I implement this? Do you have any example code?

Comment: @JuanNaym: That totally depends on your implementation. You could have a lot of "state variables" for each puzzle (unsolved/solved), different ones for items (found, charges, durability...), actors (position, experience, inventory...) and so on. You have to come up with a clever way to memorize all the important stuff yourself, since only you know what is important for your game.

Comment: Thanks for the help WillemVanOnsem and Christian König, gonna look into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of cPickle, which is faster than pickle.
Here is basic example:
    import cPickle

```
class Sample():
    def setSavePoint(self, value):
        self.savePoint=value

#First Function to save Progress
def fun():
    s=Sample()
    s.setSavePoint("Hello")
    f=open("PickleFile", 'wb')
    cPickle.dump(s, f)

#Second function to load last savepoint
def fun2():
    f=open("PickleFile", 'rb')
    state=cPickle.load(f)
    print state.savePoint
```